# SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, smtp

SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

I get this error message when i use mail() function in php script file...

I m using gmail SMTP server and gmail using STARTTLS which is secure SSL 
and i already use these commands in my contact.php file

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from","<email-address>@gmail.com>");
```

so what command i can use to enable STARTTLS or configure in php,ini file??

Comment: Example ho send email with starttls and php stream socket
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974653/authentication-failure-smtp-starttls-failed-code-220-response-2-0-0-ready/47121000#47121000

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, make sure you PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`).

You can set the following settings in your PHP.ini:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Comment: you know any other free mailing server website??
in which there is no need of ssl required.

Comment: alternatively, use `tls://smtp.gmail.com` with port 587.

Comment: Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 465,

Answer (score 0):

I know that [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) library can handle that kind of SMTP transactions.

Also, a fake sendmail with sendmail-SSL library should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Swift Mailer couldn't help either. I found a solution here: http://forum.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=73406 - so after EHLO command one needs to send STARTTLS command, enabling cryptography with `stream_socket_enable_crypto( $connection, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT );` and again EHLO command. Only this allowed me to send emails with my "stubborn" SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Swift Mailer can't do STARTTLS, however some [nice guys have written a patch for it](http://swiftmailer.lighthouseapp.com/projects/21527-swift-mailer/tickets/67-add-starttls-support).

I found patching it was a bit of a chore (probably went about it the wrong way), so have zipped it up ready for download here: [Swift Mailer with STARTTLS](http://richardwillia.ms/blog/2010/12/swift-mailer-starttls/)

Comment: **Version Note:** As of SwiftMailer v5, it supports STARTTLS out of the box. Add `setEncrpyion('tls')` or `setEncryption('ssl')` when creating transport instance. Read [more](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a false response for the following:

```
fputs($connection, 'STARTTLS'.$newLine);
```

turns out I use the wrong connection variable, so I just had to change it to:

```
fputs($smtpConnect, 'STARTTLS'.$newLine);
```

If using TLS remember to put HELO before and after:

```
fputs($smtpConnect, 'HELO '.$localhost . $newLine);
$response = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
if($secure == 'tls')
{
    fputs($smtpConnect, 'STARTTLS'.$newLine);
    $response = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
stream_socket_enable_crypto($smtpConnect, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);

// Say hello again!
    fputs($smtpConnect, 'HELO '.$localhost . $newLine);
    $response = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved,

I edited the file `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

and commented

```
-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

and changed the line from

```
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

to

```
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
```

And worked on fine

Comment: Please provide an explanation what exactly you are doing here, also I am not sure this would solve OP's problem as he probably does not have access to the file you have edited here

Comment: This conf allow Postfix to send non encrypt emails, that is you do the auth via smtp but send a not reliably message.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share my way and it worked for me after implementing following:

Open Php.ini file and fill the all the values in the respective fields by taking ref from [Gmail SMTP Settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636320064514632397-394277451&rd=1)

Remove comments from the [mail function] Statements which are instructions to the smtp Server and Match their values.

Also the sendmail SMTP server is a Fake server. Its nothing beside a text terminal (Try writing anything on it. :P).
It will use gmail s,tp to send Mails.
So configure it correctly by matching Gmail SMTP settings:

```
smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//The challenge is with Create the Transport .  Replace the following

 $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
        ->setUsername('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('xxxxxxxxx');


////With the following lines of codes


         //new Create the Transport
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.googlemail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
      ->setUsername('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
      ->setPassword('xxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution I found was to add this:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" in the [mail function]
```

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote

```
I then modified the php.ini file to use it (commented out the other lines):

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; sendmail_from = <e-mail username>@gmail.com

; For Unix only. You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

Ignore the "For Unix only" comment, as this version of sendmail works for Windows.

You then have to configure the "sendmail.ini" file in the directory where sendmail was installed:

[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=<username>
auth_password=<password>
force_sender=<e-mail username>@gmail.com

http://byitcurious.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/solving-must-issue-starttls-command.html

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score -3):

For Windows, I was able to get it working by enabling TLS for secure communication on the SMTP Virtual server. TLS will not be available on the SMTP virtual server without a certificate.  This link will give the steps needed.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4014125/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-for-outgoing-tls-authentication

Comment: Link only answers are not ideal. You should quote and comment on relevant parts of the link to make this an stand-alone answer.