# Can not send mail through PHPMailer

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

This is my php code

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("example@yahoo.com");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

My php.ini has this mail configuration
    [mail function]

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from =example@gmail.com
```

My error is

> The following From address failed: example@gmail.com Message was not
>   sent.Mailer
>       error: The following From address failed: example@gmail.com
>       SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i1sm13250552pbv.49

please help me.thanks in advance......

Comment: if you are currently running that code from localhost, that may be your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5265692/259457

Comment: Try changing the $Host to `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: http://www.vishalkumar.in/2009/06/php-mail-using-gmail-smtp-tutorial/

Comment: I tried "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" but again shows `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.`

Comment: Aren't you also missing `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`? `$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"`, username and password??! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smtp.gmail.com requires that you use SSL and port 587 or 465.

Answer (score 2):

firstly be sure  you have the last version of phpmailer()

download it from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

open class.phpmailer.php by php editor

replace all "HELO" words to "EHLO"

EHLO (not HELO) must be given by client before AUTH. (FOR GOOGLE MAIL)

it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

try phpgmailer once
 http://www.thedanglybits.com/2006/10/13/update-send-email-with-php-and-gmail-hosted-for-your-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Change your host to

```
ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
```