# PHPMailer fails to send

Tags: php, phpmailer

I see most PHPMailer questions use IsSMTP(), but I'm working from a very basic example I found yesterday on SO (can't seem to find the link in History though) that doesn't.

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

$email = new PHPMailer();

if (isset($_FILES['upload']['size']))
{
    echo 'file size: '.(basename($_FILES['upload']['size'])* 1024).'<br />';

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['upload']['name'])." has been uploaded<br />";
        $email->AddAttachment($target_path);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!<br />&nbsp;".basename($_FILES['upload']['error']);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No file was found for the upload.<br />";
}

$email->To = "me@this.com";
$email->From = $email_from;
$email->FromName = $first_name;
$email->Subject = "Query from website";
$email->Body = $email_message;

//echo "mail built...<br />";

if (!$email->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I've tried sending twice. The code executes fine and the last `if` statement returns true.

Do I have to use IsSMTP()? If so, does it have to route through SSL like I've seen suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656532/can-not-send-mail-through-phpmailer)?

Thanks in advance?

**EDIT**

I've added details required for SMTP as follows:

```
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->Host = "localhost";
$email->Port = 465;
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username   = "bacon";
$email->Password   = "4ndCh33se";
```

This doesn't seem to have triggered it to send. There also still isn't any error reported.

**EDIT**

Turns out there was an error, I had a redirect in a weird place that was preventing me from seeing it. The error is as follows:

> You must provide at least one mailer is not supported.

Comment: try to write a wrong password. Then wait for an error. Try to change the port number to 25 or 587

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that I'm not 100% sure that the credentials I'm using are correct

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. Try to write a wrong password and look for logs what happens

Answer (score 1):

Initially, the addition of the IsSMTP() seemed vital and was implemented as per other answers.

All answers failed, however, to address one missing piece of the puzzle.

PHPMailer requires at least 1 address to be added as per below. I just used the same address here as was set in the `To` property:

```
$email->To = "me@this.com";
$email->AddAddress("me@this.com");
```

Once this was done, all worked perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 for finding the problem. But it does sound like it might be a big in phpMailer. What version have you got? Is it the latest release? Maybe you could produce a test case and post a bug report on the phpMailer site.

Comment: Yeah it's the latest version. I downloaded it specifically for use in this website. I'm not even sure really what the AddAddress call is for if you're already specifying a To and From address...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send mail through `smtp` you need to set `SMTP` username and password and other setting.

And also you need to add `IsSMTP()`.

**Example Gmail SMTP setup**

```
$this->SwiftMailer->smtpType = 'tls';
$this->SwiftMailer->smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$this->SwiftMailer->smtpPort = 587;
$this->SwiftMailer->smtpUsername = 'emailaddress@gmail.com';
$this->SwiftMailer->smtpPassword = 'gmailPassword';

$this->SwiftMailer->sendAs = 'html';
$this->SwiftMailer->from = 'sender@gmail.com';
$this->SwiftMailer->fromName = 'Sender Name';
$this->SwiftMailer->to = "receiver@anything.com";

$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $email->To = "me@this.com";
    $email->From = $email_from;
    $email->FromName = $first_name;
    $email->Subject = "Query from website";
    $email->Body = $email_message;
```

I have the following besides yours. Maybe it helps:

```
    $email->IsSMTP();               // set mailer to use SMTP
    $email->Host = "mail.webaddress.com";  // specify main and backup server
    $email->SMTPAuth = true;        // turn on SMTP authentication
    $email->Username = "********";  // SMTP username
    $email->Password = "********";  // SMTP password
```

I have changed nothing in class.phpmailer.php

#### Try this

```
    $email->IsSMTP();               // set mailer to use SMTP
    $email->Host = "mail.webaddress.com";  // specify main and backup server
    $email->SMTPAuth = false;        // turn on SMTP authentication
    $email->Port = 25
    $email->SMTPSecure = "";
    $email->Username = "********";  // SMTP username
    $email->Password = "********";  // SMTP password
```

Comment: I think my biggest worry is that there's no error... The email's not sending, so surely something will have gone wrong, and yet it's not telling me? Disturbing.

Comment: If you have ability to read server logs try to look what happens. If not, ask your host what the problem can be

Comment: After my last edit (refresh the question), I can see an error now, but this hasn't made it disappear