# Send mail through SMTP error in php

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send mail with php my codes are these;

```
<?php 
include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'mertcankarayilan@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '*******';
$mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, 'Pegasus Havayolları?');
$mail->AddAddress('mertcankarayilan@hotmail.com', 'mertcankarayilan');
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = 'Ekomak';
$content = 'mailde yazan';
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href='islem-basari.php#gosterb';</script>";
} else {
    echo 'Mail gönderilirken bir hata oluştu: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

and I see a error like this:

The following From address failed: mertcankarayilan@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server

> SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k6sm56314517eep.17 - gsmtp

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265692/smtp-server-response-530-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first)

Comment: Example ho send email with smtp starttls and php stream socket
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974653/authentication-failure-smtp-starttls-failed-code-220-response-2-0-0-ready/47121000#47121000

Answer (score 0):

you must enter method 'TLS':

`$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`