# How to use imap with fsockopen behind proxy

Tags: php, authentication, proxy, imap, fsockopen

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);


// 207.46.10.10:993 hotmail imap server 

$s = "\r\n";

$proxy = '13.89.36.103'; // proxy
$port =53;

$fp = fsockopen($proxy, $port);
//socket_set_timeout($fp, 10, 0);

fputs($fp, "CONNECT 207.46.10.10:993 HTTP/1.1".$s.$s);
fputs($fp, "n1 login user@hotmail.com userpassword".$s);
fputs($fp, "n2 select Inbox".$s);
fputs($fp, "n3 UID FETCH 100289 BODY[]".$s);
fputs($fp, "n4 LOGOUT".$s.$s);

while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = fgets($fp, 4000);
    echo $line."\n";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Is it possible to use a proxy connection to read mail from a imap server using PHP's

***it work fine without proxy***
please if someone can help me i don't want to use curl

Comment: You'll need to start a new SSL communication layer after CONNECT.  Also, are you running an HTTP proxy on port 53?

Comment: You also seem to have the proxy port specified twice.

Comment: @Max this is not my proxy it's just public proxy ,you can give more details about ssl layer after CONNECT, im sure i don't need it because im using proxy and not direct connection to imap server

Comment: Port 993 is secure imap: the proxy won't do security for you.  After you send connect and the 200 response back, you then need to negotiate SSL yourself.  Incidentally, this is how https works over proxies: this was the proxy can't snoop your data.

Comment: @Max i think u are right i test it in smtp  server ant it work great, the problem is the ssl layer in imap connection i should figure out how to make proxy do ssl connection to imap server.

Comment: The proxy won't, that is your job :). You'll need to wrap your socket with SSL.

Comment: when i do it with proxy it give me just (HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established) but when i connect without proxy it give me (OK Outlook.com IMAP4rev1 server version 17.4.0.0 ready (BLU451-IMAP318) ) so i need that meesage to show when i use the proxy

Comment: Yes, after 200, it is waiting for you to begin TLS negotiations.

Comment: @Max the proxy should begin the negotiations it's not me because in that moment the proxy ho had the controlle(if you have any idea what should i change in the code thx)

Comment: @Max or you can tell me how to begin the TLS negotations

Comment: The proxy does not do TLS for you: that would be a security issue.  When you use the CONNECT verb, it is just providing a dumb pipe.  I dot not know the PHP libraries, which is why I didn't provide an answer, but surely you can search for SSL/TLS socket wrappers.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265692/smtp-server-response-530-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first  One of the answers uses stream_socket_enable_crypto to turn on SSL on an already connected socket.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$s = "\r\n";
$socket = stream_socket_client("tcp://128.199.105.86:3128", $errno, $errstr, 30);

if($socket) {

    echo "con";
    $buf = null;
    $buff = null;

    fwrite($socket, "CONNECT imap-mail.outlook.com:993 HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($socket,"Host: imap-mail.outlook.com:993\r\n");
    fwrite($socket, "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");

    while(!feof($socket)){  
    $buf .= fgets($socket, 4096);  
    if(preg_match('/^http/i', $buf)){

        break;

    } 
}  

        $modes = array( 
    STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT, 
    STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT, 
    STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT, 
    STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv2_CLIENT 
); 


$success = false; 
foreach($modes as $mode) { 
    $success = stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, $mode); 
    if ($success) {
        echo "done";
        break;
    } 
} 

 while(!feof($socket)){  
    $buf .= fgets($socket, 4096);
    if(preg_match('/^\* ok/i', $buf)){

        break;

    } 
}  
echo $buf;


    fclose($socket);



}
?>
```

the working version

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP proxy provides a dumb pipe after using the `CONNECT` verb.  Since you are connecting to a secure IMAP service, you need to enable SSL/TLS after the connection has been established.

For some searching around, it looks like you can use [stream_socket_enable_crypto](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto.php) after you get a `200` response from the PROXY server.  It is very likely you have to read the response before using `stream_socket_enable_crypto`, or it will throw an error when it reads the unexpected data.

Comment: im so close to the solution know i test stream_socket_enable_crypto but i seems not easy thanx for your help if i found somthing i tell you