# Warning: C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\mail1.php on line 9 failure email

Tags: php

```
<?php
$to = 'akhilyagna1@gmail.com';
$subject = 'this is my first php mail';
$message = 'iam akhil from yagna tech , thanks';
$headers = 'From:<akhilgundu401@gmail.com>'."\r\n".
'Reply-To:akhilgundu401@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer:PHP/'. PHPversion();
$res=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($res)
{
echo 'email sent successfully';
}
else {
echo 'failure email';
}
?>
```

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. zh13sm33324633pab.4 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\mail1.php on line 9
>   failure email

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. zh13sm33324633pab.4 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\mail1.php on line 9
failure email

Comment: when i run the code warning occur?where did i do my mistake

Comment: well, have you tried asking [search engine of your choice] what the error message means?

Comment: Have you ever checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265692/smtp-server-response-530-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP server expects a secure connection based on SSL or TLS protocol.
You should consider using a email class which can construct and send well formatted emails with SSL/TLS.

I use PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Here is a code sample to generate the Mail object, using SSL:

```
require __DIR__.'/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/**
 * Create the PHPMailer object
 * @return PHPMailer
 */
function PHPMailerFunction_mailer(){
  $mailer = new PHPMailer;
  //$mailer->SMTPDebug = 3; // Enable verbose debug output
  $mailer->Timeout = 60; // Default 300 (5 min)
  $mailer->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mailer->Host = 'smtps.servername.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mailer->Username = 'your.email@servername.com'; // SMTP username
  $mailer->Password = 'AbCdEfGh0123'; // SMTP password
  $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable SSL/TLS encryption
  $mailer->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to
  return $mailer;
}
```

Comment: what i should?iam a begginer plze help?

Comment: Go to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example
Download and install the scripts. And try to use the sample code.