# Symfony SwiftmailerBundle: Gmail sends "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.3

Over my SYmfony project I have configured the Swiftmailer to use the following email settings:

On `config.yml`:

```yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: 'smtp'
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port: '587'
    encryption: 'tls'
    username: 'gmailUser'
    password: 'gmailPasswd'
    auth_mode: 'login'
```

But when I try to send an email over my via Swiftmailer I get the response:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i61sm9367124edc.32 - gsmtp

I also tried the following settings:

```yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: 'smtp'
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port: '465'
    encryption: 'ssl'
    username: 'gmailUser'
    password: 'gmailPasswd'
    auth_mode: 'login'
```

And I try to figure out why without any idea. Do you know why?

## Edit 1:

I try to figure out if openssl is installed into php anf I run:

```
 php -m | grep ssl
```

And I get response:

> openssl

## Edit 2:

Also php has openssl support:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265692/smtp-server-response-530-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first? "First, make sure you PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`).

Comment: In tried something equivalent.

Comment: Yes it has open ssl

Comment: have you active your account from google to send from less secure application :
check the link here :
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to use the following config:

```yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: 'gmail'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
```

I guess that Swiftmailer has specific configuration for gmail.

(Or because it is pain in the neck to setup with gmail, so swiftmailer developers provided a nice pain-free alias)